# How can I remove an item from an array which render its data in a component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a component that renders some data coming from an array. I need to filter that array depending on a condition. I don't know if filter the array is the proper way, or just to remove the item I don't need from that array.

The component looks like this:

```
const PassengerCardBasedOnRoute = ({
   passengerCardId,
   isAddToMyPassengersSuccess,
   unassignedDropOffPassengers
 }) => {

  const filteredData = filterByParam =>
    filterByParam.filter(obj =>
      Object.keys(obj).some(key =>
        String(obj[key])
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()),
      ),
    );

  const componentToRenderBasedOnParams = info => (
    <View key={info.id}>
      {isAddToMyPassengersSuccess && info.id === passengerCardId && (
        <PassengersAdded name={info.name} id={info.id} />
      )}
      <PassengersInfo
        id={info.id}
        name={info.name}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const showFeedbackIfNoLength = data => {
    if (size(filteredData(data))) {
      filteredData(data).map(info => componentToRenderBasedOnParams(info));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <OptionsModal>{<AllPassengersOptionsModal />}</OptionsModal>
      <View>
        {unassignedDropOffPassengers && showFeedbackIfNoLength(unassignedDropOffPassengers)}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

The array of data I am attempting to work on is this `unassignedDropOffPassengers`. Which you may see above.
And the key function to work on is this:

```
  const componentToRenderBasedOnParams = info => (
    <View key={info.id}>
      {isAddToMyPassengersSuccess && info.id === passengerCardId && (
        <PassengersAdded name={info.name} id={info.id} />
      )}
      <PassengersInfo
        id={info.id}
        name={info.name}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

The valid condition is this:

```
      {isAddToMyPassengersSuccess && info.id === passengerCardId && (
        <PassengersAdded name={info.name} id={info.id} />
      )}
```

What I should should do is that when the condition above is met, I should remove the item from `unassignedDropOffPassengers`. Or just filter it like here where I am applying a filter:

```
  const filteredData = filterByParam =>
    filterByParam.filter(obj =>
      Object.keys(obj).some(key =>
        String(obj[key])
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()),
      ),
    );
```

What I want to know is how to achieve it/adapt it with my code. Based on the condition I mentioned above `isAddToMyPassengersSuccess && info.id === passengerCardId`.

The item in the array that I need to omit, is the one matching `passengerCardId`.

So any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I am using `lodash` btw.